# Doing substitution for long symbolic expressions with Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Mathematically, I want to compute a function $f_m(k)$, where $k$ takes on finitely many values $0,1...m-1$. For fixed $m$, I am able to generate the expression of this function for each possible value of $n$ symbolically - my aim is to compute the function values numerically, for large $m$ (wherein the function itself gets more messy).

Therefore, one way I thought was to compute the symbolic expression, then do substitution of values into these symbolic expressions. I have been using Sympy to derive these polynomial expressions (which have > 500 monomial terms in), but using

```
expr.subs([(x,x_val),(y,y_val)])
```

However, this takes a very long time. For m = 100, it takes at least a few minutes (I say at least because, after a few minutes, it is still computing).

Therefore, any ideas on how I can do this substitution in a faster way? If not, any suggestions for alternative methods?

P.S. Here is one way to generate the long polynomial functions f_m that I'm talking about, but this is not really needed for the answer (since I'm really asking about a more general problem). However, in case an example is needed, you may use this, which generates f_m symolically in 10 seconds for m = 100, for ex., but takes forever to do the substitution.

```
# Define parameters of interest - working with Sympy
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import V
import scipy.special

m = 100

V = V
phi = sym.symbols('Phi')

diag = sym.zeros(1,m)
diag[0] = 1

for j in range(2,m+1): # j = 1, i.e. m = 2
    
    f_j = sym.zeros(1,j) # Computing f as an array, so that f_j[k] is...
    #...desired symbolic expression of f_j at k
    
    for k in range(j-1): # k = 0,1
        f_j[k] = scipy.special.binom(j-1,k)*(phi*V**(k))**(j-k)*diag[k] - phi*V      

    g = sum(f_j)
    f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
    diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g

# Output of code is f_m. Doing example substituition...
f_j.subs([(V,1),(phi,2)])
```

Comment: The `$...$` math mode does not exist on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your question makes reference to `f_m(n)`, but there is no `f` nor `n` in your code. Please be consistent with your naming and explain your variables. What are `U_list` or `diag`?

Comment: I've added the necessary explanation @jared thank you for letting me know!

Comment: You have a return without a function. Also, please explain `diag`.

Comment: What diag does isn't useful for the question - what I've provided is just an algorithm to output the kind of functions that I'm interested in. That's why I haven't explained it. Return has been removed.

Comment: In your question, you say that you are building this symbolically but actually want a numerical answer in the end. If that's the case, it may be faster to just compute the numerical answer immediately without the intermediate of sympy to generate the symbolic equations. That said, I cannot follow what you're trying to build in `f_j`.

Comment: @jared - right, that's certainly another way of doing. The problem, however, is that I cannot. That's why I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do substitution. As for what $f_j$ is doing, I believe that if you try the code out, it's not so tough to see what is going on - I am simply generating an array $f_j$ where $f_j[k]$ is the evaluation of $f_j$ at k.

Comment: (1) You know for a fact that you cannot compute the result numerically without any symbolic intermediate? (2) I've tried running you code and it is extremely slow for even `m=10`. (3) You ask about substitution but don't show any substitution in your code.

Comment: (1) No, I merely know that I cannot do it numerically in the ways that I've tried. However, whether such a method exists for my particular problem is not relevant in this question. (2) For m = 10, it takes me 2 seconds to run the code - I am not sure why you are facing that problem? (3) there are really 2 variables in the array $f_j$, which are $V$ and $phi$ - not much else you can substitute? However, I'll add it in the code for explicitness.

Comment: (1) If the substitution is the slow part, then it is relevant because a purely numerical solution may be faster. (3) And that substitution step is the step that's taking a long time for you?

Comment: (1) Yes, but I think that is a more mathematical than computational issue, so it's out-of-topic for Stack Overflow. (2) Yes, for large $m$ it is the drastically more time-consuming step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254415/discussion-between-algebroo-and-jared).

Comment: How many evaluations to you plan to do?

Answer (score 0):

One way to immediately get a speed improvement is to get rid of the substitution altogether. The simplest way to do this is for you to define the values before the loops, i.e. set `V = 1` and `phi = 2`.

```py
V = 1
phi = 2

diag = sym.zeros(1,m)
diag[0] = 1

for j in range(2,m+1):
    f_j = sym.zeros(1,j)
    for k in range(j-1):
        f_j[k] = (scipy.special.binom(j-1,k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] 
                  - phi*V)

    g = sum(f_j)
    f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
    diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
```

For `m = 100`, I get a result in about 1.42s.

Now, since we are just looking for a numerical solution, we don't even need sympy, we can just use numpy. The most naive way to do this would be to just replace everything with numpy arrays.

```py
diag = np.zeros(m)
diag[0] = 1

V = 1
phi = 2

for j in range(2, m+1):
    f_j = np.zeros(j)
    for k in range(j-1):
        f_j[k] = (scipy.special.binom(j-1,k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] 
                  - phi*V)

    g = f_j.sum()
    f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
    diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
```

This is even faster, producing a result in 18.3 ms. But we can improve this even more by removing the inner loop in favor of a numpy array for `k`.

```py
diag = np.zeros(m)
diag[0] = 1

V = 1
phi = 2

for j in range(2, m+1):
    k = np.arange(j-1)
    f_j = np.zeros(j)
    f_j[k] = scipy.special.binom(j-1, k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] - phi*V

    g = f_j.sum()
    f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
    diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
```

This produces a result in 2.23 ms.

I also checked to make sure the result are the same, and they are.

```py
import sympy as sym
import scipy.special
import numpy as np

from time import perf_counter

def original(m):
    tic = perf_counter()
    phi = sym.symbols("Phi")
    V = sym.symbols("V")

    diag = sym.zeros(1,m)
    diag[0] = 1

    for j in range(2,m+1):        
        f_j = sym.zeros(1,j)
        for k in range(j-1):
            f_j[k] = (scipy.special.binom(j-1,k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] 
                      - phi*V)    

        g = sum(f_j)
        f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        
    res = f_j.subs([(V,1),(phi,2)])
    toc = perf_counter()
    print(f"original: {toc-tic}")
    return res
    

def presub(m):
    tic = perf_counter()
    V = 1
    phi = 2

    diag = sym.zeros(1,m)
    diag[0] = 1

    for j in range(2,m+1):
        f_j = sym.zeros(1,j)
        for k in range(j-1):
            f_j[k] = (scipy.special.binom(j-1,k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] 
                      - phi*V)

        g = sum(f_j)
        f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
    
    toc = perf_counter()
    print(f"presub: {toc-tic}")
    return f_j

def numpy(m):
    tic = perf_counter()
    diag = np.zeros(m)
    diag[0] = 1

    V = 1
    phi = 2

    for j in range(2, m+1):
        f_j = np.zeros(j)
        for k in range(j-1):
            f_j[k] = (scipy.special.binom(j-1,k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] 
                      - phi*V)

        g = f_j.sum()
        f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        
    toc = perf_counter()
    print(f"numpy: {toc-tic}")
    return f_j

def numpy2(m):
    tic = perf_counter()
    diag = np.zeros(m)
    diag[0] = 1
    
    V = 1
    phi = 2
    
    for j in range(2, m+1):
        k = np.arange(j-1)
        f_j = np.zeros(j)
        f_j[k] = scipy.special.binom(j-1, k)*(phi*V**k)**(j-k)*diag[k] - phi*V
    
        g = f_j.sum()
        f_j[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        diag[j-1] = 1/2 - g
        
    toc = perf_counter()
    print(f"numpy2: {toc-tic}")
    return f_j

m = 20
f_j_orig = np.array(original(m)).astype(np.float64)
f_j_presub = np.array(presub(m)).astype(np.float64)
f_j_numpy = numpy(m)
f_j_numpy2 = numpy2(m)

others = [f_j_presub, f_j_numpy, f_j_numpy2]
for res in others:
    assert np.isclose(f_j_orig, res).all()
```

---

Update: An alternative solution would be to `lambdify` the result and evaluate it. This would still allow for the Numpy evaluation. Though, if accuracy is important, the most accurate of these methods would the the pre-substitution method with sympy since that would produce an exact symbolic solution. Once converted to Numpy, the `lambdify` and pre-substitution results should be identitical.

Comment: Thanks, this analysis is very helpful! However, the issue is that I *have* tried this with my original problem, and it does not yield the correct answer. Now, I cannot share my original problem because it is part of confidential research, but the essence is that in the original problem, doing the recursion numerically for large $m$ leads to a mathematical inaccuracy for smaller $m$, which propagates to mistakes for large $m$. That is why I keep emphasizing in my question the fact that I am NOT looking for a numerical solution here - but nonetheless, thank you for your time!

Comment: @algebroo Even the pre-substituted version? I understand that maybe with floating point precision the numpy solution will have inaccuracies, but the pre-substituted version still uses sympy and should therefore be exact. If it is still not correct, then you may want to update the question (or post a new one) with a more representative example.

Comment: Again, the example is just to provide complicated polynomials, and I don't think there's anything wrong if that is my purpose with them.

Comment: Where did I say that? Either way, I don't know why you keep focusing on what is irrelevant to the question. I'm asking about numeric evaluation of long Sympy expressions, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting the same results for variables at the start and variables substituted in at the end, this is likely due to you working with Python numeric types instead of SymPy types. If you are using SymPy Rationals, the results should be the same, e.g. use `V = sym.S(1); phi = sym.S(2)` at the start and at the end you should have the same value as you would have if you did substitution. The same applies to lambdify (and I can show that for a simple example):

```py
from sympy import lambdify
from sympy.abc import x, y
from sympy import S
f = lambdify((x,y),x/y)
>>> f(1,2)  # approx
0.5
>>> f(S(1), S(2))  # exact
1/2
```

If you can't define values at the start and must substitute at the end then try lambdify and then use SymPy number types as I showed. If subs is not working then I doubt that doing `cse` will help (much) but you could try

```py
r, e = cse(f_j)
r = Dict(*r).subs(V, 1).subs(phi, 2)
e = Tuple(*e).xreplace(r)
```